# Graphs with a polynomial number of shortest paths between any pair of vertices

Tags: reference-request, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph, and let $s$ and $t$ be two arbitrary vertices of $G$. Even for some rather restricted graph classes, the number of shortest paths between $s$ and $t$ can be exponential in the size of $G$. However, for some graph classes like [block graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_graph), the number of shortest paths between $s$ and $t$ is 1 (such graphs are known as geodetic graphs).

> For what graph classes $G$ is it true that between any pair of vertices $s$ and $t$ of $G$, the number of shortest paths between $s$ and $t$ is bounded from above by $\text{poly}(n,m)$? Here, $n$ is the number of vertices, and $m$ the number of edges.

For example, are there graphs (other than block graphs) that would have a constant number of shortest paths between any pair of vertices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class of geodetic graphs includes trees, and indeed block graphs, that generalize trees.

A graph is *bigeodetic* if there are at most 2 shortest paths between any pair of vertices. The class of bigeodetic graphs contain geodetic graphs and interval-regular graphs of diameter two in which every pair of non-adjacent vertices has exactly two paths of length two between them. The cycle graph is another example.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, you might be interested in the class of [strongly regular graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph).

For your second question, cycles of odd length work since any two vertices have a unique shortest path between them. Actually any such (simple) graph would have to be either edgeless or geodetic since adjacent vertices have a unique shortest path between them.